# Sort and count unique entries in an array of strings

Tags: linux, bash, macos, sorting, unix

What I need to do is to get the list of users from `etc/group`, then sort it and then count unique entries.

Right now I only managed to get the usernames. But I suspect that it is wrong.

```
#!/bin/bash
usernames=();

while IFS=: read -r Groups Tmp1 Tmp2 Username
do
  if [ $Username!="" ];
  then
    usernames+=($Username);
  fi;
done < /etc/group
```

Then I also tried to sort it, but the output is **VERY** weird:

Sorting:

```
IFS=$'\n' sorted=($(sort <<<"${usernames[*]}"))
unset IFS
```

Output:

```
echo ${usernames[@]}
echo ""
echo ${sorted[@]}
```

Result:

```
root root root root root root _teamsserver root root _taskgated root root,_jabber,_postfix,_cyrus,_calendar,_dovecot _calendar,_jabber,_postfix _devicemgr,_teamsserver _eppc root _teamsserver _devicemgr _softwareupdate _locationd _teamsserver _devicemgr,_calendar,_teamsserver,_xserverdocs _teamsserver,_devicemgr _warmd

_calendar,_jabber,_postfix _devicemgr _devicemgr,_calendar,_teamsserver,_xserverdocs _devicemgr,_teamsserver _eppc _locationd _softwareupdate _taskgated _teamsserver _teamsserver _teamsserver _teamsserver,_devicemgr _warmd root root root root root root root root root root root,_jabber,_postfix,_cyrus,_calendar,_dovecot
```

I have zero bash experience and absolutely can't get it to work.

What I need the most basic solution to get the sort list of usernames from /etc/group with only the unique entries and print the amount of repitions of each.

For ex if I have this `/etc/group` file:

```
nobody:*:-2:
nogroup:*:-1:
wheel:*:0:root
daemon:*:1:root
kmem:*:2:root
sys:*:3:root
tty:*:4:root
operator:*:5:root
mail:*:6:_teamsserver
```

I want to get this:

```
root 6
_teamsserver 1
```

Comment: Please add a verifiable sample i/p and expected o/p. Your `/etc/group` file and your output format.

Comment: try `cut -d: -f1 /etc/group | sort | uniq -c`

Comment: Just added the desired example

Comment: @spasic: It would need to be `cut -d: -f4 /etc/group | tr ',' '\n' | sort -u | wc -l` to count the unique names, or  `cut -d: -f4 /etc/group | tr ',' '\n' | sort  | uniq -c` to count the number of occurrences of each unique name.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I misunderstood the question, thought first column of `/etc/group` was needed

Comment: You need to add spaces around the operator inside `[`: `[ "$Username" != "" ]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each 'username' field is actually an optionally empty comma-separated list of user names.  To get the user names separated, you'll need to split the entries on commas.

If I started from your loop, I'd probably use:

```
sorted=($(while IFS=: read -r Groups Tmp1 Tmp2 Usernames
          do
              if [ -n "$Usernames" ];
              then
                  echo "$Usernames"
              fi
          done < /etc/group |
          tr ',' '\n' |
          sort -u
       ))

 echo "${sorted[@]}"
```

This bypasses the intermediate `usernames` array.  If you really want that, then keep your original loop and pipe the input to `sort` through the `tr` command before `sort`:

```
IFS=$'\n' sorted=($(tr ',' '\n' <<<"${usernames[*]}" | sort -u))
```

This generates an array, `sorted`, containing the list of unique names in sorted order.

If all you want is a count of the unique names, I'd probably do the whole thing in `awk`, though.  Indeed, I'd be tempted to use `awk` instead of the `while` loop.

If you want a count of the occurrences of each unique name, then instead of `sort -u` you'd use `sort | uniq -c`.  The options and variants on the statistics are legion — the key point is that you need to split the last field of the `/etc/group` file on the commas.  If you have spaces in that list for some reason, you may have to get rid of those, too.  `tr ', ' '\n'` would do that.

Using `awk`, you could do:

```
awk -F: '{ n = split($4, a, ","); for (u = 1; u <= n; u++) count[a[u]]++i }
         END { for (u in count) print u, count[u] }' /etc/group
```

It splits the fourth field into the array `a`, then counts the occurrences of each name in the `count` array.  At the end, it prints the entries from the `count` array.  On my Mac, it yielded:

```
root 11
_warmd 1
_locationd 1
_jabber 2
_taskgated 1
_postfix 2
_devicemgr 4
_calendar 3
_cyrus 1
_teamsserver 6
_dovecot 1
_xserverdocs 1
_eppc 1
_softwareupdate 1
```

You can further sort that as required.

Comment: I'm trying to run your code but getting this error: `syntax error near unexpected token ";" if [ -n "$Usernames" ];`

Comment: There was a (major) bug — that's what happens when you don't check.  I've updated the shell code with tested code (added `$( … )` around the contents of the array assignment.  You'll still need to tweak the commands to get the result you want (eg using `sort | uniq -c` to get counts of each name).

Comment: Okay! Seems like exactly what I needed.

Comment: If we dont speak about awk, perl etc. Do you think that IFS approach is good? Maybe there is a better way to do it with regular expression for example...

Comment: And one more question: is there a way to output the result of unique counts as columns, not in a plain row?

Comment: I tend to avoid dinking with IFS; there are plenty of people who love tweaking IFS every other line of their script.  It's a perfectly legitimate way to do things, but it just so happens that it isn't the way I normally work.

Comment: There are definitely ways to present the information in a columnar fashion.  At issue is 'what is the format'.  For example, you can use `printf "%s\n" "${ordered[@]}"` to print the contents of an array one entry per line.

Comment: This prints line by line, but I want `user - count` output, just like in the example in question

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like that:

```bash
awk -F ':' '{ if(length($4)) { gsub(",", "\n", $4); print $4  } }' /etc/group | \
    sort | uniq -c
```

The `awk` command takes all non-empty 4th fields (with *':'* as separator) and replace *','* with *'\n'* in case one group has multiple users.

We then sort and count unique appearances.

Edit:

Without `awk`:

```
cut -d: -f4 /etc/group | tr ',' '\n' | grep -v '^$' | sort | uniq -c
```

Comment: If you split the fourth field into an array, and then use that array to generate a count of each username inside awk, which you'd then print at the end.

Comment: Sorry, I can't use AWK, I need pure bash solution

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear with demands in the question, upvoted for awk

Answer (score 1):

```
cut -d: -f4 /etc/group | tr , '\n' | grep '.' | \
sort | uniq -c | join -a 1 -o '1.2,1.1' - /dev/null
```

Or:

```
cut -d: -f4 /etc/group | tr , '\n' | grep '.' | \
sort | uniq -c | awk '{ print $2 " " $1  }'
```

---

How it works:

1. `cut` out field *#4*.
2. `tr` changes commas to linefeeds.
3. `grep` removes blank lines.
4. `sort`, count `uniq`ue lines, print using OP's spec.

Comment: Why `rev`?  You could simply use `cut -d: -f4` without needing `rev` at all.

Comment: I dont think I understand how is that works, but upvoted

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, you're right, thanks.  (Blame a fuzzy understanding of `/etc/group`.  I'd assumed nothing as to the number of fields, only that the *last* one was needed.)  *Duly revised.*

Answer (score 0):

Slightly modified example input to include `,` separated names

```
$ cat abc.txt 
nobody:*:-2:
nogroup:*:-1:
wheel:*:0:root
daemon:*:1:root
kmem:*:2:root,test
sys:*:3:root
tty:*:4:root,t1,test
operator:*:5:root
mail:*:6:_teamsserver

$ perl -F: -le 'foreach (split /,/,$F[3]){$h{$_}++ if /./} END{foreach (keys %h){print "$_ $h{$_}"}}' abc.txt 
t1 1
_teamsserver 1
root 6
test 2
```

- `-F:` split input line on `:` and save to `@F` array
- `foreach (split /,/,$F[3])` iterate over 4th field split on `,`
- `$h{$_}++ if /./` increment hash if non-empty
- `END{foreach (keys %h){print "$_ $h{$_}"}}` print the hash information in required format

Comment: Sorry, I cant use perl. I need pure bash solution

Comment: @s1ddok: What does 'pure Bash' mean?  Perl is a command; Awk is a command; `tr` is a command; `sort` is a command; `uniq` is a command: none of those is 'pure Bash' because Bash runs another command.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I may sound like a newbie since I have never experienced the bash programming, what I'm trying to say is that I can't use any other scripting language other than default commands

Comment: @s1ddok: You need to edit such restrictions into the question — people will use standard commands (like Awk, Perl, Python) unless you say they can't be used.