# Output awk result into latex generated pdf table on OSX

Tags: bash, macos, pdf, awk, latex

I'm using this code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39511989/sort-and-count-unique-entries-in-an-array-of-strings/39512291?noredirect=1#comment66342931_39512291):

```
awk -F ':' '{ if(length($4)) { gsub(",", "\n", $4); print $4  } }' /etc/group | \
    sort | uniq -c
```

It print this into the console:

```
   3 _calendar
   1 _cyrus
   4 _devicemgr
   1 _dovecot
   1 _eppc
   2 _jabber
   1 _locationd
   2 _postfix
   1 _softwareupdate
   1 _taskgated
   6 _teamsserver
   1 _warmd
   1 _xserverdocs
  11 root
```

Now I want get that output, and create latex table, and then generate pdf with it.

Is it possible?

Comment: Of course it's possible (even practical). But S.O. isn't a free coding service. You're expected to show your best attempt at solving the problem. Please update your Q with  you best google-fu on latex tables-> pdf. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

```
awk -F ':' '{ if(length($4)) { gsub(",", "\n", $4); print $4  } }' /etc/group \
    | sort \
    | uniq -c \
    | sed 's/_/\\_/g' \
    | awk 'BEGIN{print "\\documentclass{article}\\begin{document}\\begin{tabular}{cc}"} {printf "%s & %s\\\\\n", $1, $2} END{ print "\\end{tabular}\\end{document}" }' \
    | pdflatex --jobname table --
```

EDIT:

1. the `sed` command here ensures that underscores are transformed into `_`, otherwise LaTeX would complain that there is no mathematical mode (since `_` would be interpreted as mathematical subscript). Alternatively, one might replace all `_` with `\textunderline` which might even look better.
2. `BEGIN` and `END` in `awk` are used to print a suitable header/footer of the document
3. `pdflatex --jobname table --` means that `pdflatex` will generate a file `table.pdf` and read the input from standard input

Comment: Can you exaplin a little bit on that `sed` line? Is it possible to do it without it?

Comment: I have updated the answer...

Answer (score 2):

You can go full `gawk` (which you will need to have installed) with the following (inspired by the code from @Jonathan Leffler from the other question):

```
gawk -F: 'BEGIN {
        print "\\documentclass{article}"
        print "\\begin{document}"
        print "\\begin{tabular}{ l l l }"
    } 
    {
        nb_users = split($4, users, ",")
        for (i=1; i <= nb_users; i++) { 
            users_count[users[i]]++
        } 
    }  
    END {
        asorti(users_count)
        for (user in users_count) {
            print user, "&", users_count[user], "\\\\"
        }
        print "\\end{tabular}"
        print "\\end{document}"
    }' /etc/group | pdflatex -jobname output
```

Edit: corrections to add sort and pdf generation

Comment: It doesn't support sorting though.. + how can one generate pdf out of it?